# Site em HTML dinâmico

Tags: html5, wordpress

Sou uma desenvolvedora iniciante e faço sites estáticos em HTML/CSS. Agora, estou com um projeto de um site de notícias.

O site já está pronto, porém preciso que ele fique dinâmico, ou seja, que o cliente consiga inserir novas notícias nas páginas e também é necessário que as notícias que aparecem na home se "atualizem", dando lugar as mais novas.

Pesquisei por aí e cheguei a conclusão de que precisaria integrar esse site com o wordpress para gerar um admin, certo?

Como sou inciante, não sei bem qual o próximo passo dar. O que tenho que fazer/estudar para tornar esse site dinâmico e para que o cliente consiga trocar imagens/conteúdo tanto na home como nas outras páginas?

Comment: "Pesquisei por aí e cheguei a conclusão de que precisaria integrar esse site com o wordpress para gerar um admin, certo?" Não, não precisa.

Comment: Para seu caso mais aconselhável, é estudar um pouco wordpress, ver um tema que o cliente vai gosta, configurar e oferecer para seu cliente

Comment: O Wordpress seria uma das frameworks que você pode utilizar no projeto. É um CMS (CMS significa "Content Management System"; ou traduzindo para o português: "Sistema de Gerenciamento de Conteúdo".), é fácil de utilizar, é gratuito. Haverá sempre a curva de aprendizado, recomendo aprender a linguagem PHP antes para saber como o core do Wordpress se comporta ou pelo menos ter uma noção.

Comment: Estudar programação, estudar HTML e não vai ser do dia para a noite, para eu ficar no minimo descente em ambas áreas foram no minimo 2 anos.

Comment: Olá Gabriela, tudo bem? Bem vinda à comunidade! O que você precisa estudar é **Back End**, que basicamente é tudo que acontece antes do HTML aparecer para o usuário. Como sou desenvolvedor PHP, sugiro que tu comece com ele pode começar AQUI: https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/index.php 
O Wordpress, por exemplo, é feito em PHP.

Comment: @MarceloBonifazio o WP é um Framework trabalhado há anos, usado mundialmente, e você já navegou em muitos sites que provavelmente nem sabia serem feitos nele. Tenta não ser ofensivo assim, simplesmente em tua opinião.

Comment: Uma resposta simples e objetiva, quer criar conteúdos dinâmicos customizáveis pelos administradores da pagina? Use um banco de dados relacional, ou não relacional, faca a permissão para alterar o conteúdo usando `cookies` ou `sessions`, sendo `sessions` mais seguras que `cookies` :) // Claro que isso necessita de estudos sobre php, banco de dados e javascript, alem de segurança da informação e etc

Comment: Opnião é opnião, cada solução se encaixa a uma necessidade, eu também não sou muito fãn de wordpress, pois prefiro meter a mão na massa, mas quando eu precisei me caiu bem a minha necessidade em um momento, mas bem acho q esse não é lugar de comentar sobre isso

Comment: Procure conhecimentos de PHP e Mysql. Isso te ajudará a tornar seu site inteiramente dinâmico. Sistema de login, Gerador de conteúdo (para realizar seus posts), inserir, alterar, remover.

Conhecimetnos básicos, logo após o limite é a sua imaginação. Boa sorte pois sinceramente é uma jornada incrível de conhecimento caso você for buscar!

Comment: Olá pessoal! Obrigada pelas respostas rápidas!! A ideia mesmo é continuar estudando e traçar um caminho de aprendizado agora que me sinto um pouco mais confiante com o HTML/CSS. Obrigada @ThiagoSantos. Então, o próximo passo é estudar PHP e depois integrar esse site ao wordpress, certo?

Comment: Gabriela, o Wordpress não implicar saber PHP, você pode conseguir implementar um site simples com Wordpress sem saber PHP, seguindo apenas exemplos e tutoriais; mas isso não é indicado. O melhor seria sim aprender a linguagem da framework, seja ela qual for, isso irá ajudá-la a compreender melhor como a framework funciona. Em relação ao conteúdo da sua pergunta, sugiro que dê uma lida na [central de ajuda](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help), tem muita informação de como o SOpt funciona e principalmente os tipos de pergunta que são permitidas na comunidade. E seja bem-vinda :)

Comment: Estude programação voltada para web, pesquise sobre front-end e back-and, pesquise não somente as linguagens que compõe cada um mas a finalidade de cada. Pesquise como funciona a web à partir do momento que o usuário requisita uma página no navegador. Mas no geral é HTML/CSS/Javascript no front-end e no back-end PHP/C#/Phyton e etc e SQL para servidor, veja essas são algumas sugestões dos mais usados que vc vai obter mais documentação... Mas o mais importante é entender o processo como dito no início... Boa Sorte... E afie a vontade de ler, muitooooooo....

Comment: Ah e quando tiver dúvidas pergunte aqui, mas lembre de começar pelo [tour] para entender o funcionamento do site...

Comment: Wordpress é uma boa opção pra quem não sabe nada de programação.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Sou uma desenvolvedora iniciante e faço sites estáticos em HTML/CSS.

Você tem então experiência com um dos aspectos do perfil de desenvolvedor *front-end* - que lida com a parte da aplicação que é exposta para o usuário final.

> Pesquisei por aí e cheguei a conclusão de que precisaria integrar esse site com o wordpress para gerar um admin, certo?

Não necessariamente. Existem várias maneiras de implementar um módulo de gerência de conteúdo/recursos (CMS, da sigla em inglês *content management system*). Sim, Wordpress é um framework que você pode utilizar, e ele utilizar PHP como linguagem do lado do servidor (*back-end*), um outro aspecto do desenvolvimento de soluções web.

> O que tenho que fazer/estudar para tornar esse site dinâmico e para que o cliente consiga trocar imagens/conteúdo tanto na home como nas outras páginas?

Como mencionado, você pode utilizar WP para prover o aspecto de CMS do site.

Entretanto, se você possui experiência com JavaScript, uma opção é utilizar um framework baseado em JS e que rode no servidor via NodejS. Um destes frameworks é o KeystoneJS (http://keystonejs.com/).

A vantagem é que você não precisará aprender uma nova linguagem - ao invés disso você apenas adequará seu conhecimento atual à mecânica de soluções do lado do servidor (*server-side*).

Comment: Só lembrando que muitos clientes e estudantes usam servidor compartilhado, o que não dá para fazer muita coisa, como por exemplo executar linha de comando do node, etc. Só lembrando. Se esse framework aí depender só requisições AJAX para rodar beleza. Se pedir mais que isso...babou!

Comment: @PauloSérgioDuff eu confesso que só possuo experiência pessoal neste caso, mas a maioria dos hosts que provêem NodeJS que eu experimentei também dão acesso a um shell limitado, mas que lhe permite adicionar pacotes como o Express.

Answer (score 4):

De acordo com o que escreveu, você é estudante/desenvolvedora front-end, e por este motivo, alguns pontos são importantíssimos de adiantar antes que você se aborreça com clientes ou seu próprio código.

**HTML não é uma linguagem de programação** --> Portanto ele não processa no servidor (a tal máquina que hospeda seu site). Portanto, não é possível criar sites dinâmicos (do tipo que quer) com somente html.

**HTML5 é uma linguagem de programação** --> Alguém pode levantar este tópico. Recomendo que nenhum de vocês tratem desse assunto aqui, mas no chat, pois ele é extenso e pode desvirtuar o tópico. Resumindo, a versão 5 do HTML pode gerar esse debate, mas mesmo assim, não serve para determinar o que queres. Fiquem longe desse assunto (neste tópico).

**Wordpress não serve para todos os casos** -> Existem perfis de clientes que exigem mudanças constantes na aparência da plataforma. Muitas dessas mudanças podem não cobrir o orçamento que foi combinado (não caia no conto do template wordpress 100% modificável). Isso varia demais de acordo com o objetivo de cada um. Se esse projeto que pegou, é em partes para ampliar a experiência em desenvolvimento (front-end), não vejo problema em demorar mais que o tempo que planejou, e corrigir esse problema no seu próximo projeto. Se não for o caso, só ofereça templates prontos ao cliente, e explique que modificá-los é mais caro e fora do orçamento. Convença que vale a pena ter o seu site no ar por preço razoável num tempo razoável, que é o que o Wordpress possibilita, por causa de sua facilidade de instalação. Antes de tomar a decisão do Wordpress, dá umas perguntas em fóruns de internet por aí.

**Estude PHP** -> Não estou aqui para dizer para você se tornar uma desenvolvedora PHP. Não é isso! É que o PHP como muitas linguagens, tem função de escrever e ler em cima de arquivos. Para um projetinho rápido e de baixo custo, você pode criar um sisteminha básico de notícias e seu cliente ficar feliz da vida. Estude se é o caso antes de sair instalando o wordpress. Sem falar que sistemas dinâmicos para web, dificilmente vai escapar do PHP. O fato de usar Wordpress, você já está usando indiretamente o PHP. Sem falar que é a linguagem ideal para freelancers.

Comment: "Sem falar que sistemas dinâmicos para web, dificilmente vai escapar do PHP" [Citation Needed]

Comment: "[...] é a linguagem ideal para freelancers" [Citation Needed]

Comment: _Para um projetinho rápido e de baixo custo, você pode criar um sisteminha básico de notícias e seu cliente ficar feliz da vida_ Só pra isso também. Eu, como usuário de PHP faz bem mais de 15 anos, nunca vi algo sério e bem feito em PHP que chegasse aos pés de soluções profissionais bem básicas de mercado. PHP não é robusto, e tem uma das piores comunidades que eu já vi em termos de gente que não entende de programação, mas acha que entende.

Comment: Agora, que fique claro que tem bastante gente que usa PHP muito bem, basta não inventar de usar para as várias coisas que PHP não resolve. Exceções existem, é lógico. Só achei importante comentar, pois esse papo de "dificilmente escapar do PHP" não se aplica a coisas mais sérias, onde há uma diversidade de soluções mais adequadas. De fato, para coisas mais caseiras ou blogs, essas coisas, reconheço que o PHP é bem comum mesmo, isso é inegável.